# What program is this? It's being used for game development

Tags: game-engine

As you can see the program is being used on Ubuntu and they are using it for game development.

[image: PICTURE]

Comment: are you asking about which language is use in this program?

Comment: What you see is not a game engine, but the tool to write and debug code. If ultimately you are looking for a game engine that will run on Ubuntu I suggest you have a look Unity - http://unity3d.com/. It uses C# or Javascript for the development language, and not Java however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [icon](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=intelli+j+idea+icon&oq=intelli+j+idea+icon&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7925j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), that's [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea)

Comment: I agree with you, just curious - which icon has you identified ? Uncommon sidebar seem to be unreadable to me..
JetBrains IDE is easily recognized by me from first glance, while actual language took a second to determine analyzing keywords occurence within code editor. // Got it myself after your edit. You've recognized the dot within highlighted icon

Comment: I can see what icon is currently active, so I did a print screen, zoomed, did some image editing to highlight the edges and color and I managed to recognize it, example: http://imgur.com/a/wOkGJ and I knew the language was `Java`, so I seached for `Java IDEs`, then comparing to the google images result, it was fairly easy to find that it was IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: That's the approach !. Vice versa, I've recognized JetBrains IDE GUI, whilst IntellJ icon is not that familiar to me (compared to their other products)

Comment: @agg3l I guess deserve an upvote for tenacity hehehe